# Disable button on Parent Component if controls on Child Component haven't been selected

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-components

My parent component has a next button that should be disabled till a user enters a value in any one of the controls that the child control has.  The child control has dropdown lists, a textbox, and a date calendar control. I was thinking of using an output emitter for each of these controls and the button would be enabled if any of the value changes.  However, I don't think it'll be that straightforward and I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Here is the less simplified code
Parent component's html:

```
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeLayout">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="repair">
                <app-repair [functionTypeCode]="functionTypeCode"></app-repair>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="confirm">
                <app-confirm [actionSelected]="actionSelected" [functionTypeCode]="functionTypeCode">
                </app-confirm>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeLayout">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="repair">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" style="height: 34px" type="button">Next</button>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

Child component's html:

```
    <div class="row" *ngIf="showIfUnit()">
        <div class="col">
            <app-dropdown placeholderLabel="Find Country Code..." label="For Country Code"
                [(selected)]="selectedCountryValue" [dropdownData]="countryList">
            </app-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedExec" name="exec" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Order Date</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerOrderDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedOrderDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerOrderDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerOrderDate appendTo="body"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if a value isn't selected in the dropdown list or nothing is entered into the textbox or the date hasn't been picked from the calendar control, the button on the parent should be disabled.  Once any of those are selected on the child component, the button should be enabled.

**EDIT: Added ng-containers**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you. You can achieve that by using `@Output() informParent = new EventEmitter();`. Here is my code and stackblitz link below=>

 **Child HTML:**

```
<label>Combo From Child:</label>
  <select 
    [(ngModel)]="temp" (ngModelChange)="ngChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of countries" 
    [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<button [disabled]="isbuttonDisable">Parent From Button</button>
<br>
<child message="Message from parent to child" (informParent)="parentWillTakeAction($event)"></child>
```

**Child TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
temp:any;
  @Input() message: string;
  @Output() informParent = new EventEmitter();

  countries = [{
    id: 1, name: 'France', cities: ['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Nice']
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'Germany', cities: ['Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Munich']
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'Italy', cities: ['Roma', 'Milan', 'Napoli']
  },
  ];
 
ngChange($event){
   console.log($event);
   console.log(this.temp);
   this.informParent.emit(this.countries.find(c=>c.id==this.temp));
}
}
```

**Parent TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  messageFromChild: string = '';
  isbuttonDisable:boolean=true;
  parentWillTakeAction(message){
    this.messageFromChild = message.name+' was Selected.';
    this.isbuttonDisable=false;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Please check the [Stackblitz Link Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-1l3bev?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

there're a more simple way. If your children "inputs" is under a form, e.g. is like

```
<form #myform="ngForm">
  <label>Combo From Child:</label>
  <select name="country" [(ngModel)]="temp">
    <option *ngFor="let item of countries" 
    [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
  <input [(ngModel)]="value" name="value">
</form>
```

See that you need add "name attribute" to yours inputs if you're using [(ngModel)]

You can declare in the child the form as ViewChild

```
  @ViewChild(NgForm,{static:false}) form:NgForm
```

Well, form.dirty is true when you change some in the input, so you can access to this value from parent (for this use a template reference variable (the `#child`)

```
<button [disabled]="!child.form?.dirty">Parent From Button</button>
<child #child ></child>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-q4ncd6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: My apologies. I didn't put the ng-container that were around the components and around the button.  Your solution worked successfully, when I put the button within the ng-container of the app-repair component.  However, with the update that I put in the original post, the error I get is, "Property 'repair' does not exist on type ParentComponent.  What would be the change that I need to make?